# VBA copy a range based on values from 2 separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know what I am doing wrong. The code will run but it does not copy the data as expected, all the values seem to be overwriting to row 1 on the target sheet (tsht) instead of copying data down the target sheet. The goal here is to take data and iterate it for every county listed on the group ID tab (captured by SubCell.Value). Where plan codes and term dates match, the macro should copy each matching row from dsht for the indicated number of counties on gsht to the tsht. Can anyone see my error or why this code is keeping data all in the top row of the tsht?

```
Sub GroupID_Breakout()

Dim dsht As Worksheet 'data sheet target
Dim gsht As Worksheet
Dim tsht As Worksheet
Dim dlrow As Long
Dim glrow As Long
Dim tlrow As Long
Dim SubCell As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim Result() As String
Dim countycount As Long

Set dsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_No Formulas")
Set gsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GroupID")

'kill clunky processes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'delete compare tab if it exists
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Final").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'On Error GoTo Errhandler

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Data_No Formulas")).Name = "Data_Final" 'create new tab

Set tsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Final")

With dsht.Range("A2:CN2")
tsht.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With

glrow = gsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
dlrow = dsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each SubCell In gsht.Range("I2:I" & glrow)
countycount = SubCell.Value
Result() = Split(SubCell.Offset(0, -2).Value, ",")
    For Each rngCell In dsht.Range("A3:A" & dlrow)
    a = 0
    If SubCell.Offset(0, -4).Value = rngCell.Value And SubCell.Offset(0, -8).Value = rngCell.Offset(0, 5).Value Then
            For i = 1 To countycount
            tlrow = tsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                With dsht.Range(rngCell, rngCell.Offset(0, 91))
                    tsht.Range("A" & tlrow).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
                End With
                tsht.Range("L" & tlrow).Value = Result(a)
                i = i + 1
            Next
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next rngCell
Next SubCell

'bring back clunky processes
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox ("Macro Complete!")

Exit Sub

Errhandler:

'bring back clunky processes
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic



Select Case Err.Number
    'different error handling here
    Case Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Summary"
End Select

End Sub
```

This has been resolved with the below code, I wanted to post the resolution in case anyone finds a way to make this code work for them. Sorry I couldn't get this to copy over as clean as my 1st block.

***Solution:***

```
Sub GroupID_Breakout()

    Dim dsht As Worksheet 'data sheet target
    Dim gsht As Worksheet
    Dim tsht As Worksheet
    Dim dlrow As Long
    Dim glrow As Long
    Dim tlrow As Long
    Dim SubCell As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim Result() As String
    Dim countycount As Long

    Set dsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_No Formulas")
    Set gsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GroupID")

    'kill clunky processes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'delete compare tab if it exists
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Final").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'On Error GoTo Errhandler

    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Data_No Formulas")).Name = "Data_Final" 'create new tab

    Set tsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Final")

'pull header from dsht to tsht
    With dsht.Range("A2:CN2")
    tsht.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With

    glrow = gsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    dlrow = dsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each SubCell In gsht.Range("I2:I" & glrow)
    countycount = SubCell.Value
    Result() = Split(SubCell.Offset(0, -2).Value, ",") 'separates a list of counties by comma to reference as "Result(0)"
        For Each rngCell In dsht.Range("A3:A" & dlrow)
        a = 0
        i = 1
            For i = 1 To countycount
                If SubCell.Offset(0, -4).Value = rngCell.Value And SubCell.Offset(0, -8).Value = rngCell.Offset(0, 5).Value Then 'match dates and plan codes

                    'move row where match is found between dsht and gsht variables
                    With dsht.Range(rngCell, rngCell.Offset(0, 91))
                        tlrow = tsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                        tsht.Range("A" & (tlrow + 1)).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
                    End With
                    'place county names captured by split above with each iteration
                    tsht.Range("L" & (tlrow + 1)).Value = Result(a)
                End If
                a = a + 1
            Next i
        Next rngCell
    Next SubCell

    'bring back clunky processes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox ("Macro Complete!")

    Exit Sub

    Errhandler:

    'bring back clunky processes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


    Select Case Err.Number
        'different error handling here
        Case Else
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Summary"
    End Select

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tsht.Range("A" & tlrow).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value =
```

should be

```
tsht.Range("A" & (tlrow+1)).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value =
```

Comment: 100% it. That's only slight embarassing. Calculating the last row instead of the first available row.

Comment: Im still having an issue. For i to countycount loop is not working correctly. Instead of copying a row i to countycount number of times it is copying each matching row once. Any idea why this is happening? The countycount variable is pulling the right integer.

Comment: `i = i + 1` - typically it's bad practise to increment your loop counter inside a For Next loop.  Not sure if you meant to do that here?

Comment: Another excellent point. I hate when OPs don't post the final solution. The code now runs with expected results. See the OP solution section.